# Merge splited files with extension *.mat-001 to *.mat-012 (

Tags: matlab, extension-methods

Recently I have dealt with a series file which have extension like *.mat-001 to *.mat-012. I believe that they are Matlab files, but I cannot find a way to merge them. Can you guys please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you verify that they are mat files by loading them into MATLAB?

Comment: what do you mean by `merge them`?